# Couchapps and Users handling

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I have an instance of couchdb where I want to deploy two couchapps.

So far for registering user, I see that the rule of thumb is to use the `authentication_db` defined in the configuration file under `[couch_httpd_auth]`.

But having two couchapps means that I'll be storing informations (roles) about users from different apps within the same table `_user`.

Wouldn't that be a problem (security) if I want to replicate only one app ?

If `_user` doesn't replicate with my app how can I make sure that _user in my replicate couchdb instance will be consistent and keep the same content as my original couchdb instance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a definite limitation that currently exists within CouchDB. However, [per-database authentication](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-438) databases is scheduled for v1.2.